# debug Model validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, debugging, model

I am new to RoR and I am trying to debug a custom validation in my Model. I've tried the following in my code, as well as `puts self.input_values.inspect` and `Rails.logger.info self.input_values.inspect` but no outcome in the logs. Am I address wrong debugging? How can I check the value of self.input_values?

```
  validate :i_is_i



def i_is_i
    unless self.cust_record == 'number' && self.input_values.all? do |value|
                                       '#################'
                                       Rails.logger.debug self.input_values.inspect
                                       '#################'
                                       value.match(/^\d*$/)
                                       end
      errors.add(:input_values, "only numbers!")
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where is your validation method "record_to_i"?

Comment: if you are okay with breakpoint you can use `byebug` add a break point  and check the error details

Comment: Add a `byebug` or `debugger` to your custom validation method and debug in your console.

Comment: @ChetanMehta sorry, that was a typo when asking the question, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might not be getting printed because the condition is failing and it doesn't go inside block. Do:

```
validate :i_is_i

def i_is_i
  p "CUST_RECORD >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #{self.cust_record}"
  p "INPUT_VALUES >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #{self.input_values.all?}"
  unless self.cust_record == 'number' && self.input_values.all? do |value|
    # Stuff you wanna do when it goes inside
  end
end
```